# Calculating new attribute in Keycloak basing on some LDAP attributes

Tags: ldap, mapping, keycloak

I would ask if it is possible?..
In LDAP I have 2 attributes. I want to synchronize them into keycloak. But not 1:1.
My goal is to calculate 'in flight' new attribute in Keycloak basing on two LDAP attributes.
Can someone hint me some possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a script mapper. 
Either at the realm level in the client scopes and then a script mapper or a client level script mapper.

A random example below, try experimenting for your use case

```
/**
 * Available variables: 
 * user - the current user
 * realm - the current realm
 * token - the current token
 * userSession - the current userSession
 * keycloakSession - the current userSession
 */


function addAttribute(){
    var userDN = user.getAttribute("LDAP_ENTRY_DN")[0];
    if(userDN.lastIndexOf('ou=Employee') > -1 && token.otherClaims.groups.indexOf('Finance')){
        return 'FinanceEmployee';
    } 
    return 'NotAFinanceEmployee';
}

addAttribute();
```